# Android 8.0.0 level 26 DeadObjectException,

Tags: java, android

I'm an Android developer .

I've been facing unexpected force closes from my app

Currently, I'm using `Android 8.0.0`, `level 26` and `ROM  HuaWei/EMOTION`

Here is the logcat output:

```
--------- beginning of crash
17202-18 13:52:14.459 5182 5182 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
17302-18 13:52:14.459 5182 5182 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.sobot.custom, PID: 5182
17402-18 13:52:14.459 5182 5182 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure reading AssistStructure data: android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
17502-18 13:52:14.459 5182 5182 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1953)
17602-18 13:52:14.459 5182 5182 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1891)
17702-18 13:52:14.459 5182 5182 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.reportAssistContextExtras(IActivityManager.java:7645)
17802-18 13:52:14.459 5182 5182 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRequestAssistContextExtras(ActivityThread.java:3496)
17902-18 13:52:14.459 5182 5182 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2125)
18002-18 13:52:14.459 5182 5182 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
18102-18 13:52:14.459 5182 5182 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
18202-18 13:52:14.459 5182 5182 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7415)
18302-18 13:52:14.459 5182 5182 E AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
18402-18 13:52:14.459 5182 5182 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
18502-18 13:52:14.459 5182 5182 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

Comment: refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45432647/android-throw-deadobjectexception-with-log-transaction-failed-on-small-parcel

Comment: sorry it doesn't work for me ，They should be two issues，Because this issue only happened in Android 8.0.0

Comment: what you do in order to face that problem??

Comment: I just passed a Bundle,this Bundle is very small,and  Our logcat is also somewhat different，my log has 'android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1953)' but I am not used Parcel

Comment: Parcel is system library. By such, you need to read carefully from the other thread

Comment: I just used 'startActivityForResult()' ，so they should all be ui threads

Comment: @AlanPlusPlusPlus did you able to fix this problem? am getting same on API level 26 Android 8.0, Lenovo K8 Note india version?