# Android throw DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died just in HUAWEI Android 8.0.0

Tags: java, android, exception, android-binder, deadobjectexception

```
1804-11 09:43:24.482 22968 22968 E CrashHandler: In thread: Thread[main,5,main]
1904-11 09:43:24.482 22968 22968 E CrashHandler: UncaughtException detected: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure reading AssistStructure data: android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
2004-11 09:43:24.482 22968 22968 E CrashHandler: at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1953)
2104-11 09:43:24.482 22968 22968 E CrashHandler: at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1891)
2204-11 09:43:24.482 22968 22968 E CrashHandler: at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.reportAssistContextExtras(IActivityManager.java:7637)
2304-11 09:43:24.482 22968 22968 E CrashHandler: at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRequestAssistContextExtras(ActivityThread.java:3483)
2404-11 09:43:24.482 22968 22968 E CrashHandler: at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2125)
2504-11 09:43:24.482 22968 22968 E CrashHandler: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
2604-11 09:43:24.482 22968 22968 E CrashHandler: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
2704-11 09:43:24.482 22968 22968 E CrashHandler: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
2804-11 09:43:24.482 22968 22968 E CrashHandler: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2904-11 09:43:24.482 22968 22968 E CrashHandler: at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
3004-11 09:43:24.482 22968 22968 E CrashHandler: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:926)
```

There is many same Log before the crash.

```
06-09 16:14:11.765 22033 22033 I AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 18020 bytes, containing 1 windows, 90 views
206-09 16:14:11.780 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
306-09 16:14:11.783 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
406-09 16:14:11.789 22033 22033 I AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 18020 bytes, containing 1 windows, 90 views
506-09 16:14:11.794 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
606-09 16:14:11.796 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
706-09 16:14:11.799 22033 22033 I AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 18020 bytes, containing 1 windows, 90 views
806-09 16:14:11.809 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
906-09 16:14:11.811 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
1006-09 16:14:11.815 22033 22033 I AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 18020 bytes, containing 1 windows, 90 views
1106-09 16:14:11.824 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
1206-09 16:14:11.826 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
1306-09 16:14:11.830 22033 22033 I AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 18020 bytes, containing 1 windows, 90 views
1406-09 16:14:11.840 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
1506-09 16:14:11.842 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
1606-09 16:14:11.845 22033 22033 I AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 18020 bytes, containing 1 windows, 90 views
1706-09 16:14:11.855 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
1806-09 16:14:11.856 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
1906-09 16:14:11.857 22033 22033 I AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 18020 bytes, containing 1 windows, 90 views
2006-09 16:14:11.871 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
2106-09 16:14:11.873 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
2206-09 16:14:11.876 22033 22033 I AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 18020 bytes, containing 1 windows, 90 views
2306-09 16:14:11.890 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
2406-09 16:14:11.891 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
2506-09 16:14:11.894 22033 22033 I AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 18020 bytes, containing 1 windows, 90 views
2606-09 16:14:11.906 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
2706-09 16:14:11.908 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
2806-09 16:14:11.910 22033 22033 I AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 18020 bytes, containing 1 windows, 90 views
2906-09 16:14:11.923 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
3006-09 16:14:11.925 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
3106-09 16:14:11.929 22033 22033 I AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 18020 bytes, containing 1 windows, 90 views
3206-09 16:14:11.941 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
3306-09 16:14:11.943 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
3406-09 16:14:11.946 22033 22033 I AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 18020 bytes, containing 1 windows, 90 views
3506-09 16:14:11.959 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
3606-09 16:14:11.961 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
3706-09 16:14:11.966 22033 22033 I AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 18020 bytes, containing 1 windows, 90 views
3806-09 16:14:11.977 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
3906-09 16:14:11.979 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
4006-09 16:14:11.983 22033 22033 I AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 18020 bytes, containing 1 windows, 90 views
4106-09 16:14:11.993 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
4206-09 16:14:11.994 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
4306-09 16:14:11.995 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
4406-09 16:14:11.996 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
4506-09 16:14:11.996 22033 22033 W View : dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
```

There is a ActivityB in app，and anyone Activity jumped to this ActivityB will throw this exception **in some case**,just happened when jumping to **this ActivityB**，and **just in HUAWEI Android 8.0.0**.

I have find a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46108153/9595316) which is similar,but it doesn't work for me.

I try to use **EventBus** to transport the **bundle** between the Activity，but it still throw the exception **in some case**,just happened in HUAWEI Android 8.0.0

and I can't recurrent this exception by test.How could I solve this question?

Comment: Please post some relevant code

Comment: Sorry,There are not any relevant code.Because it just happen in some special case.I have no idea about which codes related to this.  
I have some informations about this:  
This Activity is SingleTop,I suspect it because of that.
The Crash is happened in `onResumed `

Comment: I see. There's only one place in the Android codebase where this exception is thrown, that is class `android.app.assist.AssistStructure.java`. Your solution is most likely one of the two most voted ones here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45840856/android-8-0-oreo-crash-on-focusing-textinputedittext

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 8.0 Oreo crash on focusing TextInputEditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45840856/android-8-0-oreo-crash-on-focusing-textinputedittext)

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely.There does exist a EditText in Activity,
I'm not sure if this is the correct answer,but gave me a new inspection ideas.I will try to modify it here to see if it works.

Comment: I add some code log,these logs is always before the crash,and i don't know why there are many same log before the crash.

Answer (score 1):

Finally,I set the hardwareAccelerated to false,this solution can avoid the crash,but I still don't know the reason of the crash.

```
<activity
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
</activity>
```